# Как можно стартовать цикл снова, если он закончился, но при конкретном условии?

Tags: java

Всем привет!

Недавно стал учить Java.

Возник вопрос о том, как можно начать выполнять цикл снова, но при конкретном условии.

Например, у меня есть программка которая выдает инфо по алгебраической или геометрической формуле и высчитывает по ней значения, которые задаст пользователь.

Я хочу чтобы после того, как пользователь воспользовался формулой и получил результат, получал возможность еще раз выбрать нужную формулу и использовать ее. Вот фрагмент:

```
System.out.println("Hi! This is Math Helper.");                                
    System.out.println("The programme will help you to solve your math troubles.");
    System.out.println("Which help you do need? Enter your number: ");
    System.out.println("[1] - algebra formulas, \n [2] - geometry formulas.");

    Scanner N = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int N1;                           
    N1 = N.nextInt();              

    if (N1 == 1) {                                                                          
        System.out.println("You have chosen algebra formulas.");
        System.out.println("Choose needed formula to calculate and get more info about it.");
        System.out.println("[1] - Discriminant.");
        N1 = 0;
        N1 = N.nextInt();

        while (N1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Discriminant used in quadratic equations.");
            System.out.println("General formula is D = V(b^2 - 4ac).");
            System.out.println("Write down your 'b', 'a' and 'c'.");

            int a, b, c;
            double D;
            b = N.nextInt();
            a = N.nextInt();
            c = N.nextInt();

            D = (pow(b,2)- 4*a*c);
            D = sqrt(D);

            System.out.println("Your discriminant is: " + D);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте цикл do{}while(). Или while(){}, как удобно

```
do{
  //работа программы
  System.out.println("Хотите ли выйти?(Y,N)");
  if(N.nextLine().equals("Y")){
     break;
  }
}while(true);
```

Или

```
    do{
      //работа программы
      System.out.println("Хотите ли выйти?(Y,N)");
      if(N.nextLine().equals("Y")){
         exit=true;
      }
    }while(exit==false);
```

Если "System.out.println("Хотите ли выйти?(Y,N)");" находится внутри другого цикла, находящемся в цикле while так как в первом случае мы выйдем из этого другого цикла, хотя нам нужно было выйти из цикла while.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!